# Getting zero as result (android)

Tags: android, textview

I am getting zero as the output.  I couldnt find any errors in it

any help would be great.

full code:

```
package com.equbez.resistor_decoder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Second extends Activity {
    int i,b1,b2,b3,result,four;
    String one,two,three; 
    String arr[]={"black","brown","red","orange","yellow","green","blue","violet","grey","white"};

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        EditText etone=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        one=etone.getText().toString();

        for(i=0;i<9;i++) {
            if(one.equalsIgnoreCase(arr[i])) {
                b1=i;
            }
        }

        EditText ettwo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        two=ettwo.getText().toString();

        for(i=0;i<9;i++) {
            if(two.equalsIgnoreCase(arr[i])) {
                b2=i;
            }
        }

        EditText etthree=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        three=etthree.getText().toString();

        for(i=0;i<9;i++) {
            if(three.equalsIgnoreCase(arr[i])) {
                b3=i;
            }
        }

        result=b2+b2+b3;
        Button bfour=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        bfour.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V) {
                TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);    
                tv.setText(""+result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

any help would be great.

Comment: please be more specific and its better if you post the code snipet here....

Comment: Yes i agree with  Renjith K N. Give logcat error and also that specific code.

Comment: Please don't link to code, you should provide it _here_ (I've fixed that for you).

Comment: result value always show zero

Comment: `white` is never going to compare as you have 10 elements in the array and your for loop is runs 9 time only.

Comment: i accept it we put equal sign in condition(i<=9) it may also be checked

Comment: when i enter any combination of colours i get result as zero why it so?

Comment: put a `break` statement after `b1=i;` , `b2=i;`  , `b3=i;`

Comment: Are you giving any spaces while inputing the string at the end?
once check the length of the string that you give as input whether its exact or not

Comment: i am not giving white spaces i checked it ...

Comment: i have tried break statement after b1=i; b2=i; b3=i; still it remains same

Comment: what you want to get as a result

Answer (score 2):

initially the EditTextView will be empty when the activity is called. so you always get an empty string which you are comparing to the Strings in arr[].

b1, b2, b3 are initialized to default values ie.,, '0' hence result is always '0'

write all the getText code in the `bfour.setOnClickListener()`

or else implement TextWatcher and use onTextChanged method

Comment: i tried now i getting the value  ...i had written the all getText code inside the onsetClickListener.. thanks bro....

Answer (score 1):

use

```
for(i = 0 ; i< arr.length ;i++)
do something
```

In your code if you are inputting white its not getting compared

Are you giving any spaces while inputing the string at the end? once check the length of the string that you give as input whether its exact or not

Answer (score 1):

Here i have re-coded with the changes, try out this code,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Second extends Activity 
{
    private static int b1,b2,b3,result,four;
    private String one,two,three; 
    private String arr[]={"black","brown","red","orange","yellow","green","blue","violet","grey","white"};

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        EditText etone=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        one=etone.getText().toString();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            if(one.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(arr[i].trim()))
            {
                b1=i;
                break;
            }
        }

        EditText ettwo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        two=ettwo.getText().toString();

        for( int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++ )
        {

            if(two.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(arr[i].trim()))
            {
                b2=i;
                break;
            }
        }

        EditText etthree=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        three=etthree.getText().toString();

        for( int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            if(three.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(arr[i].trim()))
            {
                b3=i;
                break;
            }
        }

        result=b2+b2+b3;
        Button bfour=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        bfour.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V) 
            {
                TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);    
                tv.setText( String.valueOf(result));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: again i am getting same zero as output

Comment: ok, i changed little bit again, `private static int b1,b2,b3,result,four;` , please try again.

Comment: Try to give a log in the if condition whether the condition is met or not (and also print the one and arr[i] elements ) and check again

Comment: @SharathG, yes, i guess that problem only, so i changed my code like that.

Comment: i am  getting result bro i placed all the getText codes inside the setOnClickListener ....nw its working

Comment: bro.... b2 and b3 variables are assigning the variable of i... but b1 variable is not assigning it ....i couldnt use the value of b1

Comment: if i declare b1 as private static int b1 it shows "the value of field b1 is never used" what it refers to??

Comment: it's a warning. dont much worry about it as you have used b1 in result calculation.

Comment: when i enter as brown in edit textbox1 it shoul correspond to value 1...it must be stored in b1 but i am getting correct output

Comment: bro i tried to upload its say code needs to be formatted ....i have uploaded file could plz refer it http://www.mediafire.com/?77rbqedm1v1nxol

Comment: for b2 and b3 the values are being assigned from i ...but for b1 alone value is not assigned from i.

Comment: thanks bro..... i have created application bro ..its now working application is an resistor decoder application it coverts the colour code to its corresponding values ...

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem. You have to run your all 3 loops after clicking the button. you have done that on Oncreate(). So you always get 0.
see below:

```
int i, b1, b2, b3, result, four;
String one, two, three;
String arr[] = { "black", "brown", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet", "grey", "white" };
EditText etone, ettwo, etthree;
Button bfour;
TextView tv;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    etone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ettwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    etthree = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    bfour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    bfour.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View V) {

            one = etone.getText().toString();

            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (one.equals(arr[i])) {
                    b1 = i;
                    System.out.println("dhrupal one="+b1);
                }
            }
            two = ettwo.getText().toString();

            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

                if (two.equals(arr[i])) {
                    System.out.println("dhrupal one="+two);
                    b2 = i;
                }
            }
            three = etthree.getText().toString();

            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (three.equals(arr[i])) {
                    System.out.println("dhrupal one="+three);
                    b3 = i;
                }
            }

            result = b1 + b2 + b3;
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            tv.setText("result=" + result);

        }
    });
}
```